# Showing '$' character not using '$' in HTML

Tags: html, ascii, non-ascii-characters

Is there any way that I show '$' (or any ascii character) without using '$'?
I mean, with TeX, 'k' is the same as ^^+. And I wonder if there is similar way to do in HTML.

Comment: As far as HTML is considered, there is never any need to escape “$”. This question apparently relates to your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053659/how-to-show-the-string-inside-a-tag-verbatim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
&#36;
```

To display a $ in HTML.