# How to show the string inside a tag verbatim?

Tags: html, tags, blogger

What tag can I use to prevent any interpretation? I need that because I need to write down some source code and it's result in blogger. I have this code in blogspot, but the code inside the `<pre>` is processed

The code is as follows:

```
<pre class='prettyprint'>
$latex \displaystyle S(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{T_{k}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{6}{k(k+1)(k+2)}$
</pre>

This is the result:
$latex \displaystyle S(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{T_{k}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{6}{k(k+1)(k+2)}$
```

[image]

When I can replace '$' in `<pre>` with something equivalent, I could avoid this issue.

I tried `<code>` and `<pre>`, but they all interpret the content.

### ADDED

I'm trying to use the javascript code found [in this post.](http://www.mymathforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=55&t=15293)

Comment: Which software and which specific code are you using to process the LaTeX code and generate the typeset formula? It’s this software (not the browser’s HTML interpreter) that needs to be told that some code is to be exempted from such processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are using [Replacemath](http://replacemath.appspot.com/static/docs.html), and its documentation says: “Should you need to to prevent certain $ signs from triggering LaTeX rendering, replace $ with the equivalent HTML `<span>$</span>` or `&#36;`, or put the code inside a `<pre>` or `<code>` block if appropriate.” Of these, the first method seems to actually work.

That is, replace all occurrences of “$” inside the `pre` element by `<span>$</span>`.

I tested this by publishing a test in [my blog](http://yuccablog.blogspot.fi/) (which had been dormant for 6 years...). I had to manually break the `pre` block to fit into the column.